# API error code 191 again

Tags: facebook, api

There are a million questions on this but for some reason I still can't get it to work.  I don't have a canvas url or base url or whatever.  My two settings are:

App Domain: mydomain.com
Site Url: calendar.mydomain.com/account/fb/

and the code I stole from fb is:

```
$app_id = $CFG['app_id'];
$app_secret = $CFG['app_secret'];
$my_url = "http://calendar.mydomain.com/account/fb/";

$code = dv($_REQUEST["code"],'');

if(empty($code)) {
 $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection

    $VIEW->dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
   . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
   . $_SESSION['state'];

 echo '<script> top.location.href="'.$VIEW->dialog_url.'"; </script>; etc...
```

actually, I'm not echoing anything, I have a view thingy, but you get the jist.
Maybe it takes sometime for all the servers to get populated.

Answer (score 1):

Other newbie programmers on the internet.  I finally figured it out.  I must be retarded.  The solution is if you're using the Zend framework and you use their suggestion redirecting through a view rather than with a header, you have to make sure the zend view thingy doens't run the redirect link through html_entities because that will garble the url and the redirect won't work.  It came to me like a bold from the blue.  I hate programming.